# Add source repositories for "Search in internet" in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

When the source of an artifact can't be found, IDEA proposes to "Search in internet" or "Attach sources". Is there a way to add a new location to the repositories IDEA checks when choosing the "search in internet" option?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to add repositories to IntelliJ Idea's "[Index Maven Repositories](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-repositories.html)" which are indexed for these types of proposals. Depending on the type of project (maven, gradle, ant, lein, sbt), the best answer will be different. In maven, you would normally edit your pom.xml file. In gradle, you would normally edit your build.gradle file. I don't know what build system you want to use (or if you want one).

If your projects are Maven projects, you can look at [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories) to see how to add another maven repository in your settings.xml file. On a project by project basis, you can add the repository to the pom.xml file instead.

Similarly, if you're using gradle then look at [gradle's documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) (Section 8.5) to add a maven repo to your projects build.gradle file.

Once IntelliJ Idea updates its indices, it will check the repositories that your project is configured to use for artifacts when it makes its proposals.

Comment: Do you mean that IDEA will check the "global" configuration (maven's .m2/settings.xml for example), or should it take into account the project-specific repositories? The trouble I have is that whilst I do have a number of additional repositories configured for the project (it's an SBT project, which uses ivy under the hood), these do not seem to be taken into account at all.